implement dask cluster with prophet
I'm trying to implement dask.
I'm currently using joblib and it works perfectly, it uses the entire CPU, which seems perfect to me
but I want to add more resources
Now trying to implement dask it's going much slower, I don't know what I'm doing wrong.
def evaluate_params(params, train, holidays, initial, periode, horizon,parallel:str="processes"):
    mae_ = 999999
    rmse_ = 999999
    df_p = pd.DataFrame()
    
    try:
        model = Prophet(**params,
                       holidays=holidays)

        model.add_country_holidays(country_name='PA')
        model.add_regressor('weekendOrPayday')
        model.fit(train)

        # Usando el paralelismo nativo de Dask en Prophet
        df_cv = cross_validation(
            model,
            initial=f"{initial} days",
            period=f"{periode} days",
            horizon=f"{horizon} days",
            parallel=parallel # change "processes" a "dask"
        )

        df_p = performance_metrics(df_cv, rolling_window=1)

    except Exception as e:
        error = f"Params {params}: {repr(e)}"
        print(error, flush=True)

    if not df_p.empty:
        mae_ = df_p["mae"].values[0]
        rmse_ = df_p["rmse"].values[0]

    return {
        'params': params,
        'mae': mae_,
        'rmse': rmse_
    }

def optimize_prophet(train, holidays, initial_days, periode_days, horizon_days):

    
    param_grid = {
        'changepoint_range': [0.8, 0.90, 0.95],
        "changepoint_prior_scale": [
            x for x in np.arange(0.01, 0.06, 0.01, dtype=float)
        ],
        "seasonality_prior_scale": [
            x for x in np.arange(1, 10.1, 1, dtype=float)
        ],
        "seasonality_mode": ["additive", "multiplicative"],
        'holidays_prior_scale': [x for x in np.arange(1, 10.1, 1, dtype=float)],
    }

    all_params = [
        dict(zip(param_grid.keys(), v))
        for v in itertools.product(*param_grid.values())
    ]


    if daskcluster == True:
        results = []
        ## with this code no run
        """future = delayed(evaluate_params)(
                        params, 
                        train, 
                        holidays,
                        initial_days, 
                        periode_days, 
                        horizon_days,
                        "dask"   
                    )
                    
        results = self.client.compute(results)
        results = self.client.gather(results)           
        """
        
        
        for params in all_params:
            future = evaluate_params(
                params, 
                train, 
                holidays,
                initial_days, 
                periode_days, 
                horizon_days,
                "dask"
            )
            results.append(future)
        client.close()
        cluster.close()

    else:
        results = Parallel(n_jobs=self.n_jobs)(
                    delayed(evaluate_params)(params, train, holidays,
                                            initial_days, periode_days, horizon_days)
                    for params in all_params
                )


    best_result = min(results, key=lambda x: x['rmse'])
    best_params = best_result['params']
    minimal_mae = best_result['mae']



    return best_params, minimal_mae

